# How to replace a matching pattern with the beginning of the line using sed?

Tags: sed

I have a file looking like this:

```
254529  ANN=C|blabla,T|blabla,A|blabla
254540  ANN=T|blabla,G|blabla,C|blabla
254586  ANN=TTGG|blabla,A|blabla
```

I want to replace commas in my file by commas followed by the number at the beginning of the line.

`blabla` in my file are actually long streches of text that I changed here for the sake of readability. Every `blabla` is different.

I tried the following but it only replaces the last comma in the line.

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\(\t.*\),/\1\2,\1\t/g' file
```

This is what I obtain:

```
254529  ANN=C|blabla,T|blabla,254529    A|blabla
254540  ANN=T|blabla,G|blabla,254540    C|blabla
254586  ANN=TTGG|blabla,254586  A|blabla
```

While I'd like to obtain this:

```
254529  ANN=C|blabla,254529    T|blabla,254529    A|blabla
254540  ANN=T|blabla,254540    G|blabla,254540    C|blabla
254586  ANN=TTGG|blabla,254586  A|blabla
```

Is this doable using sed ?

Thanks

Comment: I mean, probably? But `perl -pe '($p) = /^(\d+\t)/ or next; s/,/,$p/g'` is so much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using sed

The problem is that `g` for global substitution doesn't do overlapping substitutions.  The simple solution is to repeat the substitutions for as many times as there are commas.  Like this:

```
$ sed ':a; s/^\(.*\)\(\t.*\),/\1\2\n\1\t/; ta; s/\n/,/g' file
254529  ANN=C|blabla,254529     T|blabla,254529 A|blabla
254540  ANN=T|blabla,254540     G|blabla,254540 C|blabla
254586  ANN=TTGG|blabla,254586  A|blabla
```

How it works:

- `:a`

  This creates a label `a`.
- `s/^\(.*\)\(\t.*\),/\1\2\n\1\t/`

  This performs your substitution (slightly modified).  Since `.*` is "greedy," it performs it on the last comma in the line.

  Since `.*` is "greedy," it doesn't matter whether the `g` modifier is  applied or not:  Only the last comma will be matched and only one substitution will be performed.

  The one difference from your command is that, in the output, the comma is replaced with a newline.  This is so that we don't try to repeat the substitution on the same comma again.
- `ta`

  If the last substitution was successful, then jump back to label a.
- `s/\n/,/g`

  Convert all newlines back to commas.

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/,/, ","$1"\t")} 1' file
254529  ANN=C|blabla,254529     T|blabla,254529 A|blabla
254540  ANN=T|blabla,254540     G|blabla,254540 C|blabla
254586  ANN=TTGG|blabla,254586  A|blabla
```

Comment: I think both of those solutions will produce funny results if there are multiple tabs per input line or there is a comma in the first field.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the label command. I was searching for something like `sed '/match_the_number/ s/,/,use_the_number/'` but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: The presupposes that the whitespace following the first field is a tab. Surely it is better to work forward throughout the line and prevent the regexp engine from backtracking as much as possible?

Comment: @potong If you want to avoid backtracking, use the awk solution (included at the end of the answer).  Also, yes, the OP specified that the first field is followed by a tab.

Comment: @John1024 greed can be useful but is usually expensive, by tinkering with the regexp the solution can be more efficient  as well as self documenting e.g. `sed -E ':a;s/^((\S+)[^,]*),/\1\n\2\t/;ta;y/\n/,/' file`